# setTimeout with 0 second delay completely changes results - why?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have an **.aspx** page where I'm using a 3rd party javascript editor - **CodeMirror**. Upon switching tabs, when I leave the editor tab and go back to it - the editor's content does not refresh. This is a known issue of CodeMirror and people use a dedicated Refresh function to deal with it. In my solution I call it during **Bootstrap** tab switching via **Knockout's** data-bind. The problem is, that it doesn't work on its own, so what people do, is add a "delay":

```
setTimeout(function () {
   editor.refresh();
}, 1);
```

... and then it works. The 1 ms doesn't even matter, as **I can give it a 0 ms delay and it still works**. If I remove the setTimeout function - suddenly CodeMirror doesn't refresh (probably tries to refresh too early with correspondance to the application's current state).

So let's assume the delay is declared to be 0 ms.

1) **What is really going on here?** AM i right to understand, that the browser stumbles upon the setTimeout function, and as a rule, takes it out of the execution queue and then waits for the closest possible window for *at least* 0 ms. In practice this introduces a delay. Is that right? Or is there something else that is making this work?

2) **Is it theoretically possible that it may not work?** I mean, I would understand that on some environments, the delay may be too small for this to work, right? Also, is there actually a possibility that in a ASP.NET/knockout scenario, there may be no introduced delay?

3) **Is there any deterministic minimal delay I can calculate or deduct somehow?** Can I be confident that the delay will be at least X ms?

Generally speaking, I am not confident to commit a solution which seems to be so nondeterministic. At the moment it kinda looks like it's working because it introduces "some/any" delay. Is anyone able to shed some more light on this?

Comment: As far as I know, `setTimeout` , regardless for how long the time is set, interrupts the thread the script is running under, freeing up resources, which would allow for redraws to complete. Hence the time itself matters little to get the desired refresh effect. Although, if precise timing is needed, this explanation might help ► http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Answer (score 0):

Browsers run JavaScript the UI code in a single thread and you have to understand how **asynchronous** work in JavaScript. `setTimeout` has asynchronous callback function.
`setTimeout` makes the function is thrown into the queue and is only called when all the commands that are currently on the stack will be done.

For example:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   console.log('setTimeout');
}, 0);
for(let i = 0; i<=2; i++){
   console.log('loop');
}
```

display in console:

```
work
work
work
setTimeout
```

[image]

Comment: `JavaScript is a single-threaded` browsers run the UI code in a single thread. JS _can_ run in multiple threads, in general, it's just that most of the time, it doesn't.

Comment: @vlaz Yes it can run on many threads, and many computers as well, but it must run in a separate context. BTW most of the time JavaScript on most browsers is running on many threads, at least one for each tab and browser window, then extensions, and workers, and more.